# Laravel 5.2 orderBy relation withCount results in SQL error because of failed attempt to get column instead of count

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

The goal is to sort my campaigns by views in my filtration, which is why i have an analytics table with relations to my campaigns

My campaign model (The DB name is "ads"):

```
public function views() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Analytic', 'foreign_id', 'id')->where('foreign_type', '=', 'campaign');
}
```

The controller of my filtration:

```
$query = Ad::withCount('views')->with('tags');
$query->where("is_active", "=", 1);
$query->where("status", "=", 1);
$query->orderBy('views_count', 'DESC');
$campaigns = $query->get();
```

Now the reason for not writing it without the $query-> part, is because the query has lots of if statements depending on filtration settings.

The error im getting:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'views_count' in 'order clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `ads` where `is_active` = 1 and `status` = 1 and `from_year` >= 7 and `to_year` <= 88 and `price` >= 1000 and `price` <= 64000 order by `views_count` desc)
```

The error is it tries to fetch a column, but i can't figuere out why.
If i try to access `$campaign->views_count` in my blade template, it shows the count just fine.

Thank you for your time, i hope someone can tell me what I'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're getting is a result of a count() method not a get().
something like this

```
$query = Ad::withCount('views')->with('tags');
$query->where("is_active", "=", 1);
$query->where("status", "=", 1);
$query->orderBy('views_count', 'DESC');
$campaignCount = $query->count();
```

wich replaces the complex select part with:

```
select count(*) as aggregate
```

if you need the count() and the get(), do it like this:

```
$query = Ad::withCount('views')->with('tags');
$query->where("is_active", "=", 1);
$query->where("status", "=", 1);
$campaignCount = $query->count();

$query->orderBy('views_count', 'DESC');
$campaigns = $query->get();
```